# accessing gradient information through a driver object

Tags: openmdao

How can I most efficiently get gradient information  from the `openmdao.core.driver` `Driver` object after it has run? It has helper functions like `get_desvars`, `get_constraints`, and `get_objectives`—is there a similarly simple way to access gradient and hessian calculation results? Can I pass an argument to these functions indicating that I want gradients and/or hessians?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the calc-gradient method on the Problem instance. That is how the driver gets gradient information as well. Look at [this test](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/1bd66a6c8b1e6175cac207f580081dec4b9e1e25/openmdao/core/test/test_calc_gradient.py) to see how we call that.

This is in fact how the standard gradient based optimization drivers compute gradients. The driver's [run method](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/1bd66a6c8b1e6175cac207f580081dec4b9e1e25/openmdao/drivers/pyoptsparse_driver.py#L134) takes in a problem instance as an argument 
and then it can call [calc_gradient](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/1bd66a6c8b1e6175cac207f580081dec4b9e1e25/openmdao/drivers/pyoptsparse_driver.py#L540)

Comment: Can I call this method from a driver which is a child of a Problem? If the driver has been initialized as `prob.driver = pydakdriver()`, can I use `super` or a simillar method to access the Problem associated with the Driver? Something like `super(pydakdriver, self).calc_gadient(kwargs['av_labels'], self.get_objectives().keys())`?

Comment: I edited my answer to be a bit more complete and show you how gradient based optimization drivers compute the gradients.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Why can we directly get constraint and objective information from the driver but we not gradients?